# Firebase hosting using custom domain has SSL cert pointing to firebase.com

Tags: firebase, ssl-certificate, firebase-hosting

I am able to complete the [connect to custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) step successfully and `https://example.com` is correctly loading my static file app which is hosted on Firebase.

However, browser is warning about the site's SSL certificate is not matching `example.com`. I looked at the certificate and it is of `firebase.com`, not `example.com`.

This certificate is provided by Firebase for `example.com` (my custom domain name) and I expect it to be matching it. Is this expected?

I know the other solution is to get my own certificate for `example.com`. However, it seems that Firebase won't let me deploy my own cert.

### Update

I retried it some time back and it is fixed. And the whole suite of Firebase db/functions and corresponding sdk/cli are working really well. Great for small dev team.

Comment: hello @webp did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @drdrdrdr not yet unfortunately. However, I now host my app on google app engine and get my own ssl cert with https://letsencrypt.org/. For instructions on using letsentrypt with app engine, [this is helpful](http://blog.seafuj.com/lets-encrypt-on-google-app-engine)

Comment: @webp were you ever able to get it working with firebase?

Comment: @r3wt no, unfortunately. You have the same issue?

Comment: @webp i did. i sent support a message and they fixed it without even responding to me.

Comment: @r3wt Good to know it's something they can fix. Thanks for circling back. I may need this in the future.

Answer (score 57):

**Solution**: Don't have to do anything about it other than just wait.

Faced the same problem when connecting to my custom domain on Firebase Hosting. However, it will only be insecure when the status is `pending`. The status can be found on your Firebase Hosting Dashboard.

My connection turned secured with a green lock after around 3 hours, and the status reflected in the dashboard changed to `connected`.

Comment: Mine is also working now too, but I just received an email from the Google Search Console Team that points out the same issue. Maybe the email was delayed and now it's not a problem?

Comment: Took 30 minutes just now on one of my sites.

Answer (score 0):

This error message called domain name mismatch warning that occurs because of the domain is pointed to a shared IP addresses.

You need to confirm that your hosting provider supports SNI technology which allows install different certificates on the same IP. Please ensure that the certificate is installed correctly on your desired server and enable SNI. If your hosting provider doesn’t support SNI technology, you should have to dedicated IP to host your SSL.

Comment: Hi Jason, I've edited to clarify my question.  This "connect to custom domain" is provided by Firebase and seems not working in a appropriate manner.

Answer (score 0):

In the add custom domain menu, check by changing the `setup mode` to advanced and complete the `provide token on existing domain` task by copying the TXT value to your dns records according to the instruction.

This solved my problem.