# Firebase hosting issue external ssl certificate, domain delivered by namecheap

Tags: ssl, dns, firebase-hosting

I have an application in firebase hosted using a domain name from neamcheap but it's not working!

How to activate the ssl certificate with external domain name that i had bayed from you ( Domain name and Ssl certificate namecheap) in order to use it for firebase hosting ?

Comment: How long it has been? I can take a few hours for Firebase to provision a SSL certificate. Also try using any other device.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46651179,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.